# Delete all Child data from MySQL database tables when Parent data is deleted in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a simple project in Zf2. I am using MySql Database.
I have following tables in database.

**1. provinces**

**2. districts :** It is depended on **provinces** table. i.e, id of **provinces** table is foreign key in this table.

**3. cities :** It is depended on **districts** table. i.e, id of **districts** table is foreign key in this table.

I want to delete all the relevant data from depended tables when data from parent tables are deleted. e.g.,

1.when data from **provinces** table are deleted then data from **districts and cities** tables should be deleted.

2. when data from **districts** table are deleted then data from **cities** tables should be deleted.

I have functions in their respective tables in **Project_Name\module\Module_Name\src\Module_Name\Model**

e.g., function to delete **provinces** is:

```
 public function deleteProvinces($id)
 {
     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id));
 }
```

**$id** is id of province to be deleted.

Function to delete **districts** is:

```
public function deleteDistricts($id)
 {
     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id));
 }
```

**$id** is id of district to be deleted.

Function to delete **cities** is:

```
public function deleteCities($id)
 {
     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id));
 }
```

**$id** is id of city to be deleted.

I thinked a lot, but don't find a solution for its doing.
Any idea or suggestion is really very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may use MySQL `ON DELETE CASCADE` Referential Action.

See Referential Actions in [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

Where ever needed use the service provided by the application, in this case for MySql while creating the table you can add FK constraint ON DELETE CASCADE. This work much faster than deleting the individual rows in depended tables

I had seen multi fold performance increase when using ON DELETE CASCADE when the row count started increasing

Constraint for districts table

```
CONSTRAINT `provinces_district` FOREIGN KEY (`provinces_id`) REFERENCES `provinces` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Constraint for cities table

```
CONSTRAINT `district_cities` FOREIGN KEY (`district_id`) REFERENCES `districts` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```